# MATLAB `hold on` command causes xlim and ylim properties of axes to be adjusted incorrectly

Tags: matlab

We have this code below:

```matlab
hFigure = figure( 'position', [ 100 100 600 600 ] );
hAxes1 = axes( 'parent', hFigure, 'units', 'pixels', 'position', [ 50 350 200 200 ] );
hAxes2 = axes( 'parent', hFigure, 'units', 'pixels', 'position', [ 350 350 200 200 ] );
hAxes3 = axes( 'parent', hFigure, 'units', 'pixels', 'position', [ 50 50 200 200 ] );
hAxes4 = axes( 'parent', hFigure, 'units', 'pixels', 'position', [ 350 50 200 200 ] );

img = zeros( 200, 200, 3 );
imshow( img, 'parent', hAxes1 );
imshow( img, 'parent', hAxes2 );
imshow( img, 'parent', hAxes3 );
imshow( img, 'parent', hAxes4 );
```

Obviously, running the code would display a figure with four equally-sized black squares to be arranged in a 2 x 2 grid. However, if we add the `hold on` command before we show the `img` variable in the axes:

```matlab
hFigure = figure( 'position', [ 100 100 600 600 ] );
hAxes1 = axes( 'parent', hFigure, 'units', 'pixels', 'position', [ 50 350 200 200 ] );
hAxes2 = axes( 'parent', hFigure, 'units', 'pixels', 'position', [ 350 350 200 200 ] );
hAxes3 = axes( 'parent', hFigure, 'units', 'pixels', 'position', [ 50 50 200 200 ] );
hAxes4 = axes( 'parent', hFigure, 'units', 'pixels', 'position', [ 350 50 200 200 ] );

img = zeros( 200, 200, 3 );
hold on;
imshow( img, 'parent', hAxes1 );
imshow( img, 'parent', hAxes2 );
imshow( img, 'parent', hAxes3 );
imshow( img, 'parent', hAxes4 );
```

The last axes `hAxes4`, which is in the bottom-right corner, would show the black square with an incorrect size. Ideally, the `XLim` and `YLim` properties should both be `[0 200]`, but now, with the `hold on` command added, these two properties become `[0 250]` each and only for `hAxes4`.

I assume the reason is that, with `hAxes4` created last, `gca` is always `hAxes4` after that. Therefore, using `hold on` would only work on `hAxes4`, but why does this cause its `XLim` and `YLim` to be adjusted in this peculiar fashion?

Comment: Your assumption is correct, `hold on` applies to the current axes only. You should set `hold on` after `imshow`. Why it’s 250, I can only guess it’s some sort of default inside `imshow`. Why `hold on` affects `imshow` in this way and not, for example, `plot`? Who knows! Probably `imshow` calls multiple plotting functions, and the `hold on` causes some of them to not do their job?